# After moving to HTTPS, Google Search Console says my robots.txt is blocking all URL's in sitemap

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, sitemap, google-search-console

Yesterday I installed an SSL certificate at one of my domains, updated links and sitemap etc.

Today I went to resubmit the sitemap in Google Search Console, and to my horror it says that **5,257 out of 5,310** of the URL's in the sitemap are being blocked by `robots.txt`.

I have added the new `https` property to Google Search Console, and I get the same error when submitting the sitemap to that, as I get in the old `http` property.

Here's my `robots.txt`, available at https://adrdangerousgoods.com/robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *

Sitemap: https://adrdangerousgoods.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://adrfarligtgods.se/sitemap-swe.xml

Allow: *
```

My domain is https://adrdangerousgoods.com and the sitemap is sitemap is available at https://adrdangerousgoods.com/sitemap.xml . I tested `robots.txt` with the tool in Google Search Console, it doesn't block anything (obviously, since it's configured to allow full access).

I'm using `.htaccess` to perform `301 redirects` for all requests to `http://adrdangerousgoods.com` to `https://adrdangerousgoods.com`.

Any ideas what is going on here? Not sure if I should just try to wait it out and see if Google needs to refresh something somewhere, or if there is indeed something wrong with my sitemap/robots.txt/other stuff.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this quagmire? I having a kind of the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code as below and try:
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://adrdangerousgoods.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://adrfarligtgods.se/sitemap-swe.xml

Let me know if it works.